# Entity Framework 5 Unit of Work pattern - where should I call SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, savechanges

Apologies, in advance, if this seems like a duplicate question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075754) was the closest I could find, but it doesn't really solve the issues I am facing.

I'm using Entity Framework 5 in an ASP.NET MVC4 application and attempting to implement the Unit of Work pattern.

My unit of work class implements `IDisposable` and contains a single instance of my `DbContext`-derived object context class, as well as a number of repositories, each of which derives from a generic base repository class that exposes all the usual repository functionality.

For each HTTP request, Ninject creates a single instance of the Unit of Work class and injects it into the controllers, automatically disposing it when the request is complete.

Since EF5 abstracts away the data storage and Ninject manages the lifetime of the object context, it seems like the perfect way for consuming code to access in-memory entity objects without the need to explcitly manage their persistence. In other words, for optimum separation of concerns, I envisage my controller action methods being able to use and modify repository data without the need to explicitly call `SaveChanges` afterwards.

My first (naiive) attempt to implement this idea employed a call to `SaveChanges` within every repository base-class method that modified data. Of course, I soon realized that this is neither performance optimized (especially when making multiple successive calls to the same method), nor does it accommodate situations where an action method directly modifies a property of an object retrieved from a repository.

So, I evolved my design to eliminate these premature calls to `SaveChanges` and replace them with a single call when the Unit of Work instance is disposed. This seemed like the cleanest implementation of the Unit of Work pattern in MVC, since a unit of work is naturally scoped to a request.

Unfortunately, after building this concept, I discovered its fatal flaw - the fact that objects added to or deleted from a `DbContext` are [not reflected, even locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990618), until `SaveChanges` has been called.

So, what are your thoughts on the idea that consuming code should be able to use objects without explicitly persisting them? And, if this idea seems valid, what's the best way to achieve it with EF5?

Many thanks for your suggestions,

Tim

UPDATE: Based on @Wahid's response, I am adding below some test code that shows some of the situations in which it becomes essential for the consuming code to explicitly call `SaveChanges`:

```
var unitOfWork = _kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
var terms = unitOfWork.Terms.Entities;

// Purge the table so as to start with a known state 
foreach (var term in terms)
{
    terms.Remove(term);
}

unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

Assert.AreEqual(0, terms.Count());

// Verify that additions are not even reflected locally until committed.
var created = new Term { Pattern = "Test" };
terms.Add(created);
Assert.AreEqual(0, terms.Count());

// Verify that additions are reflected locally once committed.
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
Assert.AreEqual(1, terms.Count());

// Verify that property modifications to entities are reflected locally immediately 
created.Pattern = "Test2";
var another = terms.Single(term => term.Id == created.Id);
Assert.AreEqual("Test2", another.Pattern);
Assert.True(ReferenceEquals(created, another));

// Verify that queries against property changes fail until committed
Assert.IsNull(terms.FirstOrDefault(term => term.Pattern == "Test2"));

// Verify that queries against property changes work once committed
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
Assert.NotNull(terms.FirstOrDefault(term => term.Pattern == "Test2"));

// Verify that deletions are not even reflected locally until committed.
terms.Remove(created);
Assert.AreEqual(1, terms.Count());

// Verify that additions are reflected locally once committed.
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
Assert.AreEqual(0, terms.Count());
```

Comment: I feel like I have the same problem as you. Coming from NHibernate, I'm used to having INSERT and DELETE statements go to the database directly, so that when I lateron try to SELECT the object (in the same DbContext session) I actually get my result. I would expect SaveChanges() to just commit the transaction, but it seems like EF delays all INSERT/DELETE statements until you call SaveChanges(). Did you ever figure out a way to get it to do what you (and by extension, I think, we) want?

Answer (score 7):

**First** of all `SaveChanges` should **NOT be ever in the repositories at all**. Because that's leads you to lose the benefit of `UnitOfWork`.

**Second** you need to make a special method to save changes in the `UnitOfWork`.

And if you want to call this method automatically then you may fine some other solution like `ActionFilter` or maybe by making all your Controllers inherits from `BaseController` class and handle the `SaveChanges` in it.

**Anyway the `UnitOfWork` should always have `SaveChanges` method.**

Comment: Many thanks for your response. My latest implementation does all of the things that you suggest and it already includes a mechanism to call SaveChanges when the HTTP request ends (based on Ninject's InRequestScope binding). But this doesn't solve the problem that the object context can get into an invalid state, even within the scope of a single unit of work, if the consuming code modifies something without explicitly calling SaveChanges. I will update my question with some code to show this.

Comment: in case of using "Service Layer", where each service has a refrence to `UOW`. Where should i call `SaveChanges` so that I can reuse specific service method in other services ?

Comment: For me I pass an optional parameter to confirm save changes in the service layer methods `AddEmployee(Employee model, bool save = true)` If I didn't pass this parameter then the service will save the changes.